# How to add value to an array on click event

Tags: jquery, arrays

What I am trying to achieve is to read value on click event and save it to an array. My code:

```
<a href='#' class="hotel" data-hotel-name='Holiday Inn'>Add to favourites</a>
```

```js
var hotelName = [];    
$('.hotel').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    hotelName.push( $(this).data('hotel-name') );
});    
console.log(hotelName.length);
```

The output is always `0`. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is fine, you just need to read the `length` of the array *after* you modify it in the `click` handler:

```
var hotelName = [];    
$('.hotel').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    hotelName.push( $(this).data('hotel-name') );
    console.log(hotelName.length); // < read the length of the amended array here
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/z3mpkcyc/)

Comment: Yes, definitely. But you need to use them *after* the click event has placed some items in the array. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/z3mpkcyc/3/. Click the links to fill the array, then the button to see what's in the array