# Jquery: How to get variable outside event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

This my code.

```
   /**
     Sticky Header
    **/
    var $h_height;

    $(".site-header").sticky({
        topSpacing:0,
    });
    $('.site-header').on('sticky-start', function() {
        $h_height = $(this).outerHeight();
    });
    $('.site-header').on('sticky-end', function() { $(this).parent().css('height', 'auto'); });

    console.log($h_height);
```

I would like to put our variables ($h_height) out of the function. 
I used console.log to display. it show undefined

Comment: Move the `console.log($h_height);` inside the handler. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100698/how-to-add-value-to-an-array-on-click-event) post

Comment: I would like to make it can be used outside the function.

Comment: Well techincally, it CAN be used outside of the function.  Youre just console.logging it before its defined.  If you put setTimeout(console.log($h_height),1000);  you'll see it will be defined beause you give the page time to load

Comment: @JayzanarakProgrammerLoso I prefer you to wrap code under one block as give in my answer below then it will give you desired result . let me know if it helps you

Comment: well it is undefined until your on('sticky-start'... has fired.

Comment: It is already useable from outside the function but the point you are missing is the value is defined after you are printing it using console. Post your exact scenario how you want to use the variable.

Comment: @ymranx I would like to use $h_height variable outside the handler fucntion. after sticky-start event triggered and i will use it in `setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('.sticky').unstick();
            $(".sticky").each(function(){
                $(this).sticky({ topSpacing: $h_height });
                $(this).on('sticky-end', function() { $(this).css('position', 'relative'); });
            });
            $('.sticky').sticky('update');
        }, 100);`

Answer (score 1):

To Make Global Variables in Jquery

```
var a_href;
jQuery(function(){
    $('sth a').on('click', function(e){
        a_href = $(this).attr('href');

          console.log(a_href);  
         //output is href value of clicked link

        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

If you want to print value using Console.log Then remember we are setting its values after some event triggers . So by default its value could be undefined as it is undefined by default and its value gets set after a particular event like click event in my case

**Jquery Fiddle To Show How To Trigger Value of Global Variable in Jquery**

```js
//Global Variable 
var a_href;

//Global Variable Value Triggered After Button1 Click
 $('#bt').on('click', function(e){
        a_href = $("#tx").val();

   alert(a_href);
          //console.log(a_href);  
         //output is href value of clicked link

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    
    //Global Variable Value Triggered After Button2 Click
     $('#bt1').on('click', function(e){
        a_href = $("#tx1").val();

       alert(a_href);
          //console.log(a_href);  
         //output is href value of clicked link

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="hh" id="tx" />
<input type="button" value="Button1" id="bt" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" value="hh1" id="tx1" />

<input type="button" value="Button2" id="bt1" />
```

Comment: @JayzanarakProgrammerLoso in order to make the variables global try declaring it in global scope

Comment: I do the way you say. But it didn't work. I would like to get some variables can be used outside the handler. $('.site-header').on('sticky-start', function() {
        $h_height = $(this).outerHeight();
    }); console.log($h_height);

Comment: @JayzanarakProgrammerLoso I am going to add a fiddle to my answer that Will work like global variable in jquery you can get reference from it

Comment: @JayzanarakProgrammerLoso See the jquery fiddle a_href is global variable whose value is changed by button1 and button 2 click differently

Comment: @JayzanarakProgrammerLoso ok welcome , if it solved your problem please accept the answer so it may help others also